# ActiveMq Inflight Count not decreasing

Tags: activemq-classic

I am using activemq 5.5.0 version in my project.

I am facing one problem due to some reason my inflight count keep on increasing , 
Rate of increment is not high.

After some days it will become equal to prefetch size then my queue stops responding.

Could anyone can help me how to make inflight count 0 without deleting the queue ?

Comment: Do you actually have a consumer for all messages on that destination, is your consumer (or consumers) actually consuming messages, and is your consumer actually acking the messages it consumes?  If the answer to any of those is "No", that's your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the in-flight count go to 0 by purging the queue from the web console (there's a Purge link on each queue on the Queues page); that will delete all messages in the queue without deleting the queue itself.

That will satisfy the question as you've asked it, though I suspect it's not really what you want and what you meant was "without deleting any messages from the queue".  But if I'm wrong and this is what you wanted, then great; if not, answer my questions in the comment I added and we'll go from there.